# Importing first three and last three fields from CSV with variable number of fields

Tags: r, regex, read.csv, ragged

I've got a data set in csv. Unfortunately each line has different amount of "," commas. I am interested in importing only first 3 and last 3 variables from the file in R.

in example:

`> line: "A","B","C","D",...,"X",Y","Z"`

I want to achieve the following `

`> line: "A","B","C","X","Y","Z"`

I tried to use grep, to find - by using of regural expressions - first 3 variables:

```
new_data <- grep("([^,]+)(,[^,]+){2}", dataset, values=TRUE)
```

After that operation it shows me all lines in which that expression exists.

How can I remove the following variables in the line using grep, if it is possible, how can I remove the whole interval (each variable from <3;n-3>).

Do you now other method to solve that problem?

Comment: "Unfortunately each line has different amount of commas/fields". This can be called a "ragged" file or "variable number of fields".

Comment: Do you want a solution inside R, or a command-line one, as @VarunM gives?

Comment: Inside R solution will be cool, I am trying now to implement "awk" solution provide by Varun.

Comment: Sorry, I saw grep and assumed that command line solutions would be ok. I don't even follow `r` on StackOverflow. I hope my answer helps you though!

Comment: Thank you for your solution ;)

I tried to implement it in R, but i received the following error: 

"Error in system(awk_call, intern = intern) : 'awk' not found" 

For now I don't know why, but when i will figure it out I will share that knowledge

Comment: The R approach is `textConnection -> string operations -> read.csv(data=...)`

Comment: Thanks both of you. I would like to give you +rep, but I cannot, cause of insufficient amount of mine.

Comment: @Meyk, your problem is already solved I'm sure but I thought it might help you to know how to use the `awk` solution using the `system` command as well. Check out the edit in my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a combination of `apply` and `head` and `tail`:

```
d2 <- data.frame(t(apply(d1, 1, function(x) c(head(x[x != ''],3), tail(x[x != ''],3)))))
```

resulting in:

```
> d2
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
1  a  b  c  x  y  z
2  a  b  c  g  h  i
3  a  b  c  t  u  v
```

Using the data of @VarunM:

```
d1 <- read.csv(text='a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v', header = FALSE, fill = TRUE)
```

Comment: @VarunM used your data for conveniance ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Try awk-

```
awk -F, '{print $1, $2, $3, $(NF-2), $(NF-1), $(NF)}' file
```

`-F,` changes the field separator to a comma.

`NF` is the last field in the dataset.
`NF-1` and `NF-2` are obvious.

I made a sample file-

```
$cat file.csv
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z 
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v
```

On doing-

```
$awk -F, '{print $1, $2, $3, $(NF-2), $(NF-1), $(NF)}' file.csv
```

Output-

```
a  b  c  x  y  z 
a  b  c  g  h  i
a  b  c  t  u  v
```

## Edit

This solution works perfectly well if you do the following-

```
> system('awk -F, \'{print $1, $2, $3, $(NF-2), $(NF-1), $(NF)}\' file.csv')
```

Where file.csv is the file containing the data.

Answer (score 1):

Command-line solutions will be easier, but if you want a solution inside R, in R code, then filter the incoming CSV through a textConnection and use string operations or regex to extract the first and last three fields:

```
csvConn <- textConnection('your.csv')
<use string operations or regex to extract the first and last three fields>
read.csv(data = csvFixed, ...)
```

This works, I've done it before.
See other similar solutions involving [textConnection and read.csv(data=...)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=textConnection+read.csv+data). I couldn't find a very clean example though.